# Erro ao executar uma Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linha-de-comando

Preciso executar algumas tasks customizadas, porém, sempre que eu tento, recebo a seguinte mensagem: `Application has been already initialized.`
Procurei em vários locais, inclusive no SO em Inglês, mas sem sucesso. Parece não ter uma solução definitiva. Minha aplicação está funcionando normalmente, com Puma e Nginx. Meu arquivo de tasks está assim:

```
namespace :access do
    require "modules/blockade.rb"

    desc "Block everybody"
    task block: :environment do
        (...)
    end

    desc "Unblock everybody"
    task unblock: :environment do
        (...)
    end
end
```

E este arquivo do `require`, basicamente assim:

```
require "#{ENV["PWD"]}/config/environment.rb"

module Blockade
    (...)
end
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Não cheguei a testar mas algo me diz que essa linha:

```
require "#{ENV["PWD"]}/config/environment.rb"
```

está causando seu problema.
O que você precisa fazer exatamente para ter que dar um require no environment.rb?

Se você apenas precisa carregar variaveis de ambiente procura por essas gems:

[foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)

[figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)